# How to make footer responsive for mobile view using angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material with angular to make a footer but the problem is , in mobile view it is not looking good. For mobile view I want the structure like this

Heading 1

login

register

---

Heading 2

FAQ

Contact us

---

HTML:

```html
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div style="font-family: 'Nunito'; font-weight: bold; color:yellow;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          margin: 0;
          min-width: 0;font-weight: 400;
          line-height: 1.5;
          font-size: 16px;">
            Heading 1
        </div>
        <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item href="/login">Register</a>


            <a mat-list-item href="/login">Log in</a>

        </mat-nav-list>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div style="font-family: 'Nunito'; font-weight: bold; color:yellow;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
             min-width: 0;font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.5;
             font-size: 16px;">
            Heading 2
        </div>

        <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item href="/attend">FAQ</a>

            <a mat-list-item href="/host">Contact Us</a>
        </mat-nav-list>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want the footer to be responsive according to the stucture, I am mentioned above below . What needs to be done in the code to make it possible.

Comment: See this example: https://codepen.io/surabhi/pen/grBOBQ (the Clickable Footer one)
Also, it would help if you posted working mocked code in somewhere like https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: It is working in big screen but for mobile view it is not responsive

Comment: Have you tried clicking the footer in that example? When reducing the screen width, the options are reorganised

Comment: Yes it is reorganized for mobile view but It is not looking good

Comment: I want as per the structure I mentioned above @adrisons